# Processing URL parameters - name value pairs separated by slashes

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, url-routing, mod-rewrite

I want to have URLs like :-

```
URL 1 -    www.projectname/module/search/param/1
URL 2 -    www.projectname/param/1/module/search
```

I want a PHP code which takes the above URLs as parameter and returns an array like

```
Array("module" => "search", "param" => 1) (for URL 1)
Array("param" => 1, "module" => "search") (for URL 2)
```

So that I can use the result as $_GET in my project. I came to know that it would be better and easier to do this with PHP than with htaccess rewrite rules. If you can help with rewrite rules also please help.

There can be any number of parameters.

I got this idea from CodeIgniter's URL handling library. But my project is not on Codeigniter so I cant use that library. Any standalone code to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe Zend_Router (check for spelling errors) can be separated from the ZF and be used just for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function to do the job.  Note that I've filled out the URLs, as `parse_url` needs the scheme.  It will also fail on seriously malformed URLs.

```
function get_dispatch($url) {
    // Split the URL into its constituent parts.
    $parse = parse_url($url);

    // Remove the leading forward slash, if there is one.
    $path = ltrim($parse['path'], '/');

    // Put each element into an array.
    $elements = explode('/', $path);

    // Create a new empty array.
    $args = array();

    // Loop through each pair of elements.
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i = $i + 2) {
        $args[$elements[$i]] = $elements[$i + 1];
    }

    return $args;
}

print_r(get_dispatch('http://www.projectname.com/module/search/param/1'));
print_r(get_dispatch('http://www.projectname.com/param/1/module/search'));
```

Here's the result:

```
Array
(
    [module] => search
    [param] => 1
)
Array
(
    [param] => 1
    [module] => search
)
```

However, this probably is not very robust.  If there is a well written library out there that already does the job (like the one suggested by Itay Moav), then you should definitely look into it.

Comment: @Georg Schölly: Thanks for the edit.  I'd forgotten about l/trim's ability to strip other characters.

Comment: You should really thank the anonymous user that made the first edit, I didn't change that much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP function `parse_url` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

So you can then analyse the `path` section of the array.

You cold then use `explode` to put items into an assoc array?

Answer (score 0):

Use php [explode](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. You will have to parse the result and see if the $result[1](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is a valid module in your application an so on. The logic of the parser should belong to your application. Zend_router that somebody mentioned does the same thing by trying to map to an existing module/controller/action whatever $request object it has.

```
$result = explode('/', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url    = parse_url('http://www.projectname.com/module/search/param/1');
$params = explode('/', trim($url['path'], '/'));
$params = array_chunk($params, 2); //tricky part here
foreach($params as $param)
{
    $final_params[$param[0]] = $param[1];
}
```

edit: parse_url works with correct URLs only

[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is a nice function for this task :)